# Isn't $V^n$ a $\Bbb K$-vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a $\Bbb K$-vector space. Let $n \in \Bbb N.$ Can't we say that $V^n$ is also a $\Bbb K$-vector with respect to component wise addition and component wise scalar multiplication? If so what can we say about $\dim (V^n)$ in terms of $\dim (V)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed a vector space. Also, if $V$ is finite dimensional and $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is a basis then it is easy to prove that the set:

$\{(e_1,0),(e_2,0),...,(e_n,0),(0,e_1),(0,e_2),...,(0,e_n)\}$

is a basis of $V^2$, and hence $\dim(V^2)=2\dim(V)$. It follows by induction that $\dim(V^n)=n\dim(V)$.

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely right. Thanks for your help.